# Scala function syntax type declaration

Tags: scala

While doing Scala exercise I encountered this compilation problem by mistake which got me curious.

This is my FoldLeft implementation :

```
@annotation.tailrec
def foldLeft[A, B](l: List[A], b: B)(f:(B, A) => B): B = l match {
  case Nil => b
  case Cons(head, tail) => foldLeft(tail, f(b, head)) (f)
}
```

Using this FoldLeft I am creating sum function.

```
def sum1(l: List[Int]): Int = foldLeft(l, 0) (_ + _)
def sum2[A](l: List[Int]): Int = foldLeft(l, 0) (_ + _)
def sum3[Int](l: List[Int]): Int = foldLeft(l, 0) (_ + _)
```

sum1 and sum2 compiles and runs fine, however sum3 which looks similar to sum2 (used Int instead of A) does not compile saying "Can not resolve reference + signature".

Answer (score 3):

In `sum3`, all `Int`s in the signature are the type parameter, not the `scala.Int` type. That is, `sum3` is the same as

```
def sum4[A](l: List[A]): A = foldLeft(l, 0) (_ + _)
```

In `sum2`, the type parameter is pointless because it isn't used anywhere. The compiler will probably nearly always infer it as `Nothing`.